# IP URL with Port is not working in cURL PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

IP URL with Port is not working in cURL PHP

```
$url = 'http://IP:PORT/API_URL';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $curlData;
```

Above code is return `Error: Failed to connect to [IP] port [PORT]: Connection refused` with latest PHP and timeout with older PHP.

Second Case:

```
    $url = 'http://IP/API_URL';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, [PORT]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
    $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
    echo 'curl_getinfo: ';
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
    echo "</pre>";
    if (curl_errno($curl)) {
        echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $curlData;
```

And the output of the above case is:

```
curl_getinfo:
Array
(
    [url] => http://IP:PORT/API_URL
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.201014
    [namelookup_time] => 2.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
Error: Failed to connect to [IP] port [PORT]: Connection refused
```

Comment: You need to use "CURLOPT_PORT" to provide a port

Comment: I added this `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, [PORT HERE]);` but it returned same error.

Comment: And you did remove the port from the initial URL? What is your return from:
curl_getinfo($curl);

Comment: what's the server os? also I assume endpoint you are trying to connect is working.

Comment: @Tyralcori Yes, I removed the port, I updated code at description.

Comment: @dryize Linux OS Ubuntu

Comment: So as you can see, the HTTP Response Code comes with "0" - can you check the endpoint / address, which you are trying to  curl, if you see an incoming request? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Tyralcori I am not getting you, Yes my endpoint is correct, if run same code in local then it is working.

Comment: @Tyralcori Yes it is working if i called this direct url using browser.

Comment: So if i get this correctly: the code is working on your local machine - you can call the ip / port in your local browser, but it's not working when you upload the code somewhere?
if so, it seems the ip is not reachable from the server where the code is uploaded - can you tell us more about the connection between the server where the code runs and the ip that should be called?

Comment: @SteBächler Code is already uploaded at server, if am calling my other project url that ip is same but without port then it is working, but it not working with this url.

Comment: @SteBächler `http://IP/OTHER_PROJECT_API` without port is working.

Comment: `http://IP:PORT/API_URL` it is working in the browser, but not working using PHP cURL.

Comment: Try whether different url works. Like https://google.com it could be SELinux or firewall

Comment: @dryize Yes other URL is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would test if the port is open. You can use `telnet IP PORT`. High chance the port is being blocked. Another possibility is that you're trying to connect to a port which forces SSL. Which you have clearly inactivated in your code. Try generating a valid certificate and try again.

Comment: `Trying [IP]...
Connected to [IP].
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: I got this. I already tested after removing ssl inactivated code but didn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I just enabled the port.